# Opening .xlsm files not opening via .bat file (cmd prompt)

Tags: excel, windows, vba, batch-file, cmd

I recently started experiencing an issue with a series of .bat files I schedule to open via the **"Task Scheduler"** in Windows 10. These tasks and batch files were working perfectly for over a year and now they are giving me fits.

Here is the code in the batch file which I created in Notepad and saved as a `.bat` file.

```
  @echo
    cd C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram
    IorpiaSCHSet1.xlsm
    cd C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram
    IorpiaSCHSet2.xlsm
    cd C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram
    IorpiaSCHSet3.xlsm
    cd C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram
    IorpiaSCHSet4.xlsm
    cd C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram
    IorpiaSCHSet5.xlsm
    cd C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram
    IorpiaSCHSet6.xlsm
    cd C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram
    IorpiaSCHSet7.xlsm
    cd C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram
    IorpiaSCHSet8.xlsm
```

The first `.xlsm` file should open, some auto macros will run and excel will close down (as is written in the VBA of the macro). Upon excel closing, the next command should execute and open the next `.xlsm` file. As I stated, this worked perfectly for years.

I now will get a command that just sits there and does not open the file (could be the 2nd file, could be the 7th file). The first file will always open but after that it's random as to the file or command that gets stuck and simply does not open.

*Is there some better code I can use to FORCE the files to open?* Running as administrator has not helped. Changing the location of all the files has not helped. Rebuilding the files does not help.

I am able to schedule a task that opens these batch files and witness them complete 100% but it never fails that when I schedule in the middle of the night, I wake up to an incomplete batch file, hanging on a command.

I have also tried the following commands to no avail ...

```
Start \wait \k "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Macros\Myfile.xlsm"

C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Macros\Myfile.xlsm
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated ...

Comment: Two questions -
Are you in control of what the macros (and workbooks) look like?
Are other script languages an option (which can be launched from a .bat)?

Comment: @Sam, yes I am in control of the macros & workbooks. Other script languages are certainly an option if they will achieve the desired result ... which is ... opening the `.xlsm` files one by one and not before the previous `.xlsm` file has been closed.

Comment: @Sam If you have any suggestions on other script languages, what script to use and best way to launch from .bat that would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Start \wait \k "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Macros\Myfile.xlsm"` That should have give you an immediate error because you are not using the options correctly. Can't say I have ever seen a program use a backslash to specify a command line option or argument.

Comment: I wonder if Excel has been updated? By default Excel's Trust Center settings will not allow VBA code to run. Your first batch task attempting to run a .xlsm file would in such circumstances open Excel then hang as the macro code would be denied - what happens to other tasks I could not guess. Just a suggestion to check.

Comment: @Squashman, that was my mistake on the backslashes. I did code it correctly in batch file.

Comment: @StewartRoss, the issue is not with excel opening and hanging. That is not an issue. The issue is in the .bat opening and hanging on the command to open one of any 8 different `.xlsm` files. I have witnessed the entire process complete perfectly as recently as yesterday. However, every time I schedule and walk away for the night I always come back to a hanging `.bat` file.

Comment: How is the Scheduled Task configured?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an old classic VBScript approach. I picked it since I think you will have the shortest start from Excel VBA.
Create a file named something.vbs and put this in it:

```
OpenWorkbook "C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram\IorpiaSCHSet1.xlsm"
OpenWorkbook "C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram\IorpiaSCHSet2.xlsm"

Sub OpenWorkbook(Path)
    Dim Excel, wb
    Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Excel.Visible = True
    Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Path)

    Set Excel = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

In your bat file, call it like this:

```
cscript something.vbs
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate the issue but on my machine it worked flawlessly.

However, this workaround might help you:

```
@ECHO OFF

CD C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram

START /MIN /WAIT CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet1.xlsm
START /MIN /WAIT CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet2.xlsm
START /MIN /WAIT CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet3.xlsm
START /MIN /WAIT CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet4.xlsm
START /MIN /WAIT CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet5.xlsm
START /MIN /WAIT CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet6.xlsm
START /MIN /WAIT CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet7.xlsm
START /MIN /WAIT CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet8.xlsm
```

I cannot ensure you that this will work, but as the first `.xlsm` file always opens, chances are that a new enviroment will do the same for every other `.xlsm` file.

Whether this fixed your problem or not, try to recreate this problem in a virtual machine. Maybe the issue is connected to some update, another program or something in your windows.

---

### Edit:

If it's still not working give this a shot:

```
@ECHO OFF

CD C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram

SET n=1

:next_file
IF %n% GTR 8 EXIT
IorpiaSCHSet%n%.xlsm
SET /A "n=%n%+1"
CALL :check_status
GOTO :next_file


:check_status
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME EQ EXCEL.EXE" |FIND ":" > nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK && GOTO check_status
EXIT /B
```

Or this:

```
@ECHO OFF

CD C:\Users\JonC\Desktop\Macros\IorpiaSCHProgram

START /MIN CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet1.xlsm
TIMEOUT /T n /NOBREAK > nul
START /MIN CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet2.xlsm
TIMEOUT /T n /NOBREAK > nul
START /MIN CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet3.xlsm
TIMEOUT /T n /NOBREAK > nul
START /MIN CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet4.xlsm
TIMEOUT /T n /NOBREAK > nul
START /MIN CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet5.xlsm
TIMEOUT /T n /NOBREAK > nul
START /MIN CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet6.xlsm
TIMEOUT /T n /NOBREAK > nul
START /MIN CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet7.xlsm
TIMEOUT /T n /NOBREAK > nul
START /MIN CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet8.xlsm
```

Replace `n` with the time the according macro needs (in seconds).

If one of the solutions works, but the CMD windows are still open when the last macro finished, add `TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe` at the end.

Comment: @ FatalBulletHit, Thanks for the info. That left the same result. I did notice that when running the `.bat` file it opened 2 cmd windows and they were both blank, however, the first file opened and kicked off correctly. No more after that. Just blank cmd's and no files opening. Any thoughts on which programs could be impacting the `.bat` ability to open the files?

Comment: Does the `.xlsm` file close itself after it did the task? If not, this would explain why nothing happens. As `@ECHO` is set `OFF` the CMD window will stay blank at all time.

Comment: The first file did close down. All the `.xlsm` file have VBA code in their auto macros to quit excel once the code is complete.

Comment: Maybe change `START /MIN /WAIT CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet1.xlsm` to `START /MIN CMD /C IorpiaSCHSet1.xlsm & TIMEOUT /T n /NOBREAK >nul 2>&1` where `n` is time in seconds. This is everything but perfect, but the 2nd CMD window should close after `n` seconds and then start the next file - in theory...

Comment: that option is opening all files simultaneously. I would need each file to open, then auto macro runs for that file, then VBA within auto macro instructs excel to quit ... then the next command is executed with the next `.xlsm` file opening.

Comment: @Jon are you positive that Excel is completely closing down?  Check task manager to see if there is still an instance running.

Comment: Just to be sure here: Did you replace `n` with a number? E.g. `TIMEOUT /T 10 /NOBREAK >nul 2>&1` for a 10 second break?